Touchpad mouse keys are not detected from time to time - how to analyse and solve this for Lenovo T14 Gen2 in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS?
My Lenovo T14s Gen2 laptop has a touch-pad with three mouse keys above it (left | middle | right mouse key).
Since approximately two weeks, I have the issue, that - perhaps for ten minutes - these three mouse keys do not work. So I can press them but the action is not executed.
E.g. Rebooting, suspending and returning all do not change this.
What does help: just wait for (perhaps) 10 minutes. Then those keys will work again.
After suspending this issue might come up again.
Where (e. g. in which log file) could I analyze for the root cause?
If somebody already knows it: what is the root cause and how can I repair it permanently?
PS: workaround is presently to use the touch-pad itself to execute left and right mouse clicks.
More details:
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

wmctrl -m
Name: Compiz
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF

printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"
Desktop: Unity:Unity7:ubuntu
Session: unity

UPDATE:
when pressing / releasing one of the three buttons, in /var/log/sylog and /var/log/kern.log
I can  see the following entries:
... computer kernel: [ ...] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6

Sometimes the following entries are created:
... computer kernel: [ ...] psmouse serio1: issuing reconnect request

... computer kernel: [ ...] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.

None of these entries does "cure" the behaviour.
